# DirectDraw issue with .Net Framework 4 and higher

Tags: c#, video, directshow, directshow.net

I am working on a project that plays a video with **FilgraphManagerClass**. The project is working properly in .Net Framework 3.5 but when I upgraded the project to framework to 4 or higher, DirectDraw load the file with problems which makes it almost unusable. Is there anybody else who encountered the same problem?

[image]
Figure 1- .Net Framework 3.5

[image] 
Figure 2- .Net Framework 4

```
    public bool LoadFile(string sfile, Form parentHandler)
    {
        graphManager.RenderFile(sfile);

        try
        {
            parentHandler.Left = 0;
            parentHandler.Top = 0;

            parentHandler.Width = graphManager.Width;
            parentHandler.Height = graphManager.Height;

            mControl = graphManager;
            mPosition = graphManager;
            mWindow = graphManager;
            mWindow.Owner = parentHandler.Handle.ToInt32();
            mWindow.WindowStyle = WS_CHILD;
            mWindow.SetWindowPosition(parentHandler.ClientRectangle.Left,
                parentHandler.ClientRectangle.Top,
                parentHandler.ClientRectangle.Width,
                parentHandler.ClientRectangle.Height);

            parentHandler.Opacity = 1;
            m_objMediaEvent = graphManager as IMediaEvent;
            m_objMediaEventEx = graphManager as IMediaEventEx;
            m_objMediaEventEx.SetNotifyWindow((int)parentHandler.Handle, WM_GRAPHNOTIFY, 0);
            mPosition = graphManager as IMediaPosition;
            mControl = graphManager as IMediaControl;
            m_objBasicAudio = graphManager as IBasicAudio;
        }
        catch (Exception) { mWindow = null;  return false; }
        finally
        {
            graphManager.Run();
            m_CurrentStatus = MediaStatus.Running;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It does not look like that it's .NET version. Stock H.264 decoder is known to give artifacts like this when under debugger, try to run standalone. It is not DirectDraw either (the subject).

Comment: I noticed that if we run this code inside Visual Studio, it creates aforementioned noise but if we run the same application from outside (bin folder), it works perfectly. I have no idea why.